# Need to align table under image and place another table directly to the right of the image/table column

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, alignment

I'm trying to help my mom out over break making a webform she can use in her office and I'm 100% self taught, so any help is incredibly appreciated. Basically, I'm trying to put an image fully left aligned on the page with a table directly under it, a larger table to the right of the image, and another table to the right of that. Right now, I can't get the first table to be directly under the image- it keeps going left aligned but under the second table (which is much larger than the first)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<img src="{{logo}}" style="float:left; height: 80px; width: auto; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;"><div>

<table style="float:right; background-color:#CCCCCC" border="1"><tbody><tr><td width="125px">#:&nbsp;<u>{{customerID}}</u><br>Sq Ft:<u><input type="text" style="width:50px"></u><br>Linear Ft:<u><input type="text" style="width:50px"></u><br><input type="checkbox">Live Infestation<br><input type="checkbox">Prevention<br><div style="padding-left:20px">Treatment</div><br><br><small><i></i></small><i></i><center><i><small>For Office Use Only</small></i></center></td></tr></tbody></table>

<table style="float:left; margin-left:100px" border="1"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center"><b>Termite Inspection Graph &amp; Treatment Specifications</b></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height:1.4"><u>{{customerName}}</u><br><small>Name</small><br><u>{{customerAddress}} {{customerCity}} {{customerState}} {{customerZip}}</u><br><small>Address/Zip Code</small><br><u>{{customerPhone}}, {{customerEmail}}</u><br><small>Phone, Email</small><br><u>{{billingAddress}} {{billingCity}} {{billingState}} {{billingZip}}</u><br><small>Bill To Address</small><br><u><input type="text"></u><br><small>Agreement/Treatment is limited to the one structure listed above unless specified here</small></td></tr></tbody></table><br>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><table style="float:left; background-color:#D0F0C0" border="1"><tbody><tr><td><small><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon + Termidor&nbsp;<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon + Altriset<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Termidor Only<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Altriset Only<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon Only</small></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

For reference, it's the last chunk of code I'm having trouble with. Side note, the software she is using does not allow me to edit the CSS, so everything I do needs to be within the HTML code itself.

All help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use css in the HTML page within  tags this should work for you:
@media part of the CSS is to make the columns stack instead of sit next to each other on a narrow screen such as a phone; make sure to do testing and tweaking with the actual content to see if it behaves as intended.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body { /*display: inline-block;*/ }
    #image { width: 25%; margin: 15px;}
    #righttable { float: left; width: 20%; margin:  10px;}
    #lefttable { float: left; width: 20%; margin: 10px;}
    #midtable { float: left; width: 50%; margin: 10px;}
    div.row { width: 100%; }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #image { width: 100%; }
    #righttable { width: 100%; }
    #lefttable { width: 100%; }
    #midtable { width: 100%; }
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
<img id="image" src="{{logo}}" style="height: 80px; width: auto; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;"></div>
<div class="row">
<div id="lefttable">
<table style="background-color:#D0F0C0" border="1"><tbody><tr><td><small><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon + Termidor&nbsp;<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon + Altriset<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Termidor Only<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Altriset Only<br><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sentricon Only</small></td></tr></tbody></table></div>

<div id="midtable"><table style=" /*margin-left:100px*/" border="1"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center"><b>Termite Inspection Graph &amp; Treatment Specifications</b></td></tr><tr><td style="line-height:1.4"><u>{{customerName}}</u><br><small>Name</small><br><u>{{customerAddress}} {{customerCity}} {{customerState}} {{customerZip}}</u><br><small>Address/Zip Code</small><br><u>{{customerPhone}}, {{customerEmail}}</u><br><small>Phone, Email</small><br><u>{{billingAddress}} {{billingCity}} {{billingState}} {{billingZip}}</u><br><small>Bill To Address</small><br><u><input type="text"></u><br><small>Agreement/Treatment is limited to the one structure listed above unless specified here</small></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>
</div>

<div id="righttable">
<table style=" background-color:#CCCCCC" border="1"><tbody><tr><td width="125px">#:&nbsp;<u>{{customerID}}</u><br>Sq Ft:<u><input type="text" style="width:50px"></u><br>Linear Ft:<u><input type="text" style="width:50px"></u><br><input type="checkbox">Live Infestation<br><input type="checkbox">Prevention<br><div style="padding-left:20px">Treatment</div><br><br><small><i></i></small><i></i><center><i><small>For Office Use Only</small></i></center></td></tr></tbody></table></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit the style, either. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: The same method should work provided you can create the DIV elements and put the styling in those. Like this: `<div class="row" style="width: 100%">` and `<div id="lefttable" style= "float: left; width: 20%; margin: 10px;">` and `<div id="midtable" style = "float: left; width: 50%; margin: 10px;">` and `<div id="righttable" style = "float: left; width: 20%; margin:  10px;">`    - If you have to use the style tags on the tables, it's gonna be a bit fiddly with margin and padding but you can probably get it more or less how you want it without DIV elements if you need to.

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but I can't get that to work either. Where in the code should these pieces go? Is it before the table code starts?

Comment: Each div would go before each table is created, and then remember to close the tag with a `</div>` tag which would come after the respective `</table>` tag.

Comment: Hmm, it still won't place the leftmost table at the far edge of the page and places it to the right of the logo. Thank you for all of your help, though! I'm completely self-taught, so anything else I learn is always helpful. I'll keep working with it.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work with a table. It sounds like you've got a lot of limitations with the software so any way you had to wrangle it is fair enough. I still have a lot to learn as well, the grid system seems to be really cool but even though I've done a basic project with it using a tutorial I am not very familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this works by cheating the system and just putting the top image as the first row of the table that needs to be directly under it